# Agents not connecting to OpsCenter via STOMP, UI displays question marks in the STOMP column

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

The previous DBA created and connected a cluster (4 nodes) to DSE OpsCenter. It's almost perfect (nodes are connected and visible) except for the STOMP service.

In the `OpsCenter -> Nodes -> Agents` there are question marks in the STOMP service column.

What should I check first?

The firewall seems to be ok, like in the other 3 clusters, which work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The [DataStax Enterprise (DSE)](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) node [agents communicate with the OpsCenter server over STOMP](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/docs/6.8/opscArchOvr.html). The yellow question mark in the [Agents Status View](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/docs/6.8/online_help/opscNodeAdminAgents.html) in the OpsCenter UI indicates that OpsCenter doesn't know the status of the agent because OpsCenter can't talk to it.

You stated that "the firewall seems to be ok" but you didn't provide details of what you think is "ok". You need to specifically check that there is connectivity between OpsCenter and the agents.

The `opscenterd` daemon listens for TCP traffic from the agents on `stomp_port` which by default is port `61620`. The agents listen for TCP traffic from the OpsCenter server on `agents_api_port` which by default is port `61621` (see [OpsCenter ports reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/docs/6.8/reference/opscLcmPorts.html) for details).

Once you've confirmed that bi-directional network traffic is working between OpsCenter and the agents, you need to check the following logs for clues:

- `/var/log/opscenter/opscenterd.log` on the OpsCenter server
- `/var/log/datastax-agent/agent.log` on the nodes

The errors in the logs will give you clues as to why OpsCenter cannot connect to the agents.

And as a friendly reminder that if you need assistance with troubleshooting the problem, you should log a ticket with [DataStax Support](https://support.datastax.com/) and one of their engineers will help you. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!